# Modify error message while uploading large file or a file with special characters

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

In SharePoint 2013 library, When we upload a large file, it gives an error:

> Sorry, for some reasons this document can not be uploaded

Or when we upload a file with special characters, it says:

> File names cant contain the following characters:....

I need to modify the wordings of these messages but I am not able to find out what are the resource files from which these messages are coming from. I checked on 15 hive but there are lots of `.resx` files.

Can someone please give me the file name so that it will save a great amount of time for me?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying files in hive is not recommended as they tend to get overwritten during service pack installations or by configuration wizard.

Comment: Du. Yes, this point has been highlighted. I just need it to do a PoC. Please let me know the file names.